# Extra character in the index using exercise package

Tags: exercises

I'm using exercise package and I want the list of the exercise in the index.
In texlive2019 (mac) I did not have any problem. Now, with texlive2020 (mac), I get the list of the exercises in the index, however each value is followed by a "t".
Here the code:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
%
\usepackage{exercise} 
\renewcounter{Exercise}[chapter]% Reset counter every chapter
\renewcommand{\theExercise}{\thechapter.\arabic{Exercise}}%
\begin{document}
%
\author{Author Name}
%
\title{The proof}
%
\maketitle
%
\tableofcontents
%
\ListOfExerciseInToc
\ExerciseLevelInToc{section}
%
%
\chapter{gas}

\begin{Exercise}[difficulty=1]
bla
bla
bla
\end{Exercise}
\begin{Exercise}[difficulty=2]
blo
blo
blo
\end{Exercise}

\chapter{energy}

\begin{Exercise}[difficulty=3]
blu
blu
blu
\end{Exercise}
\begin{Exercise}[difficulty=1]
bli
bli
bli
\end{Exercise}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in `exercise.sty` that has a disastrous `\expandafter` in two places

```latex
   \addcontentsline{\ext@exercise}{\toc@exercise}{\ExerciseName\
        \theExercise\ \expandafter{\itshape \ExerciseTitle}\hspace{.66em}}
```

This token is completely wrong and should be removed. Its effect is to untimely expand `\itshape` that should instead remain as is. An internal change in LaTeX made the error pop up; previously it went unnoticed by pure chance.

Contact the package maintainer; in the meantime you can fix it yourself.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
%
\usepackage{exercise,etoolbox}
\renewcounter{Exercise}[chapter]% Reset counter every chapter
\renewcommand{\theExercise}{\thechapter.\arabic{Exercise}}%

% fix the wrong code in exercise.sty
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@@@ExeEnv}{\expandafter}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@@@Execmd}{\expandafter}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
%
\author{Author Name}
%
\title{The proof}
%
\maketitle
%
\tableofcontents
%
\ListOfExerciseInToc
\ExerciseLevelInToc{section}
%
%
\chapter{gas}

\begin{Exercise}[difficulty=1]
bla
bla
bla
\end{Exercise}
\begin{Exercise}[difficulty=2]
blo
blo
blo
\end{Exercise}

\chapter{energy}

\begin{Exercise}[difficulty=3]
blu
blu
blu
\end{Exercise}
\begin{Exercise}[difficulty=1]
bli
bli
bli
\end{Exercise}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That solved the problem. BTW is there a way to get the "difficulty" printed also in the Index?

Comment: @AlbyStalks I don't know. Consult the documentation of `exercise`